# FPS при работе с Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, drawbitmap

Делаю логическую игру для Android. 
И все было бы хорошо, если бы не одно НО... При рисовании с помощью surfaceview возникает проблема, когда нужно отрисовать много объектов. FPS проседает до 25-30.
Конкретнее:

Есть двумерный массив клеток поля (targets) и такой же по размеру массив элементов, которые нужно передвигать (balls). В методе отрисовки игрового поля я сначала пробегаю по массиву клеток, а после - по массиву элементов.

```
private void presentField(){
   Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
   fieldCanvas.drawRect(0,0,fieldBitmap.getWidth(),fieldBitmap.getHeight(),clearPaint);

    for(int j=0;j<world.getLevel().getSizeJ();j++){
        for(int i=0;i<world.getLevel().getSizeI();i++){
                            drawGameElement(world.getLevel().getField()[i][j],j,i);
        }
    }

    int chipI=0;
    int chipJ=0;

    for(int j=0;j<world.getLevel().getSizeJ();j++){
        for(int i=0;i<world.getLevel().getSizeI();i++){
            fieldCanvas.drawBitmap(elementBitmap,j*200+getBallShiftX(candyElement),i*200+getBallShiftY(candyElement),null);
            //}
            if(world.getLevel().getBalls()[i][j].getColor()!= GameElement.ElementColor.CHIP) {
                drawGameElement(world.getLevel().getBalls()[i][j], j, i);
            } else {
                chipI = i;
                chipJ = j;
            }
        }
    }

    drawGameElement(world.getLevel().getBalls()[chipI][chipJ],chipJ,chipI);
    g.drawBitmap(fieldBitmap, dstRect);

}
```

Вот метод, который выполняет отрисовку:

```
private void drawGameElement(GameElement element, int x, int y){
    Bitmap atlas=null;

    int candyShiftX=0;
    int candyShiftY=0;

    if(element instanceof Target){
        if(element.getColor()== GameElement.ElementColor.CHIP){
            fieldCanvas.drawBitmap(Assets.chipTarget, x*200,y*200, null);
        } else {
            atlas=Assets.targets;
        }
    } else if (element instanceof Ball){
        candyShiftX=getBallShiftX((Ball) element);
        candyShiftY=getBallShiftY((Ball) element);

        if(element.getColor()== GameElement.ElementColor.CHIP){
            fieldCanvas.drawBitmap(Assets.chip, (x*200)+candyShiftX,(y*200)+candyShiftY, null);
        } else {
            atlas=Assets.candys;
        }
    }

    if(atlas!=null){

        atlasRect.left=getPicIdByColor(element.getColor())*200;
        atlasRect.top=0;
        atlasRect.right=(getPicIdByColor(element.getColor())*200)+200;
        atlasRect.bottom=200;

        fieldDstRect.left=(x*200)+candyShiftX;
        fieldDstRect.top=(y*200)+candyShiftY;
        fieldDstRect.right=(x*200)+200+candyShiftX;
        fieldDstRect.bottom=(y*200)+200+candyShiftY;

        fieldCanvas.drawBitmap(atlas,atlasRect,fieldDstRect,null);
    }
}
```

По скольку размер поля у каждого уровня разный, я рисую поля и элементы не в основной Bitmap, а во вспомогательный. Когда я пробегаю по обоим массивам,я рисую вспомогательный Bitmap в основной.

Картинки элементов и полей я храню в атласах (кроме поля и элемента, которым нужно управлять, но не думаю, что эта подробность тут важна).

На первых уровнях все работает отлично - к примеру, размер поля 3 на 3, FPS - 60. Но когда размер поля становится 5 на 6, то FPS падает вдвое, а то и больше.

Кто-нибудь знает способ, как выровнять FPS при таком количестве элементов?

Вот класс Assets:

```
public class Assets {
    public static Bitmap background;
    public static Bitmap curtain;
    public static Bitmap loadingLabel;
    public static Bitmap playButtonLabel;
    public static Bitmap aboutButtonLabel;
    public static Bitmap winLabel;
    public static Bitmap targets;
    public static Bitmap candys;
    //public static Bitmap blueBall;
    //public static Bitmap redBall;
    public static Bitmap chip;
    //public static Bitmap blueTarget;
    //public static Bitmap redTarget;
    public static Bitmap chipTarget;
    public static Bitmap lockedPack;
    public static Bitmap pack1;
    public static Bitmap pack2;
    public static Bitmap lockedLevel;
    public static Bitmap levels;
    public static Bitmap escapeLabel;
    public static Bitmap escapeButtons;
    public static Bitmap lives;
    public static Bitmap lowEnergy;
    public static Bitmap cat;
}
```

Картинки я получаю из папки Assets через AssetManager:

```
    Assets.targets = g.newBitmap("targets.png");
```

Вот мой метод newBitmap:

```
public Bitmap newBitmap(String fileName) {

Bitmap bitmap=null;
InputStream in=null;

try{
    in = assets.open(fileName);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

    if(bitmap==null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from asset '"+fileName+"'" );
} catch (IOException ex){
    throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from asset '"+fileName+"'" );
} finally {
    if(in!=null){
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: покажите класс Assets, если это то что я думаю, то совершенно не удивительно

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Добавил в описание.

Comment: ну то, что я и думал, я даже не знаю с чего начать, кончено чистая java не даст perf, для игр, но здесь можно очень сильно оптимизировать работу. Начиная с .png, смотреть что там, если альфа не нужен, то это даст сильный рост производительности, каждый раз вы напрягаете Assets, открываете поток, кстати не видно где вы bmp нарезаете, это нужно сделать один раз до самой игры, потом использовать, как угодно и сколько раз, это даст очень сильный прирост, смотреть саму отрисовку, что там - я уверен что можно и там оттюнить, короче есть над чем поработать, а ведь я даже не вчитывался и не тестил.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, спасибо большое за советы! я новичек в этом деле, поэтому хотелось бы уточнить пару деталей. На счет альфы - ее убрать получится только из одного атласа. Вы написали "кстати не видно где вы bmp нарезаете". Я использую png. Есть ли существенная разница в использовании этих двух форматов? Нарезать в начале - метод createBitmap(Bitmap,int,int,int,int)? Вместо этого я это делаю в отрисовке:fieldCanvas.drawBitmap(atlas,atlasRect,fieldDstRect,null); Загрузка из Asset происходит перед началом уровня, в каждом шаге отрисовки потоки не создаются.